# Code for Longest Common Subsequence is not showing result properly

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working for a program that solves the problem of finding the maximum length of Longest common subsequence in given two strings, I've observed it doesn't show me the first character of my 2 strings in the resultant matrix.

Example - Two strings are

- BDCABA
- ABCBDAB

Result -

[image: Result]

---

> There is no fault in the Algorithm, but probably there may be some
>   glitches in my C code.

Code -

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
    #include<string.h> 
    #define size 20 
    char A[size],B[size]; 
    int i,j,A_len,B_len;
    int score[size][size];
    void main() 
    { 
        printf("\tEnter first string\n\t");
        scanf("%s",A);
        printf("\tEnter second string\n\t");
        scanf("%s",B);
        printf("\n");
        A_len = strlen(A); 
        B_len = strlen(B); 
        A[0] = ' ';
        printf("\t      ");
        for(i=1;i<=B_len;i++) 
            printf("%5c",toupper(B[i]));
        printf("\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<=A_len;i++) 
        { 
            for(j=0;j<=B_len;j++) 
            { 
                if(i==0 || j==0) 
                    score[i][j]=0; 
                else if(A[i] == B[j] ) 
                    score[i][j] = score[i-1][j-1] + 1; 
                else 
                {
                    if(score[i][j-1]>score[i-1][j])
                        score[i][j] = score[i][j-1];
                    else
                        score[i][j] = score[i-1][j];
                }
            } 
        }
        for(i=0;i<=A_len;i++)
        {
            printf("\t%c",toupper(A[i]));
            for(j=0;j<=B_len;j++)
                printf("%5d",score[i][j]);
            printf("\n\n"); 
        }
        if(score[A_len][B_len] != 0)
        {
            printf("Longest common subsequence is of %d length :\t",score[A_len][B_len]);
        }
        else
            printf("longest common subsequence not found");
    }
```

The code is **returning correct result** for all strings, but it is not showing input string names in result as they are provided, it skips the first character of both strings, and unfortunately I am getting no reason for this behavior, please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apppend this code after 15th line of your code, and Delete your previous 16,17,18 and 19th line. It is working.


I guess ,the problem you are facing is because you are reading string with %s and you want to compare your string after first letter so that you can place a 0 there, *Right* ?

---

```
    for(i=0;i<A_len;i++) 
        temp[i+1] = A[i]; 
    for(i=1;i<=A_len;i++) 
        A[i] = temp[i];
    A[0] = ' ';
    for(i=0;i<B_len;i++) 
        temp[i+1] = B[i]; 
    printf("\t      ");
    for(i=1;i<=B_len;i++) 
    {   
        B[i] = temp[i];
        printf("%5c",toupper(B[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your A[0] = ' ' is overwriting your first character in the first input string. And for B your first print loop start from i =1, which again misses the first character of second string.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that in C the lowest index of an array is always 0. Thus, you must not set `A[0]=' '`, should start your loops with 0, and end them with `i<length_X` (not `<=`).

But then, you should also adopt the algorithms logic (`A[0]==B[0]` *is not* a miss, thus `i==0|j==0` is not reason to set `score` to 0.